# Getting Type error while opening an uploaded CSV File

Tags: python, django, file-upload, csv, django-forms

I'm developing an application in python with django. User can upload a CSV file. I use file upload to get the file. But, it's not stored any where. I try to take it from request to process the file. While I'm trying to open the file, it gives an error. I use the CSV library exists in python to process. Form elements and attributes used as per django. Request object which I try to take the uploaded file is also django designed object.

```
import csv
from rootFolder.UploadFileForm

def uploadFile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            paramFile = open(request.FILES['uploadFile'], 'rb')
            portfolio = csv.DictReader(paramFile)
            users = []
            for row in portfolio:
                users.append(row)
```

This below line gives the error.

```
paramFile = open(request.FILES['uploadFile'], 'rb')
```

The given error is :

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found
```

Please kindly give your suggestion if you got any idea on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

open() takes the name of the file as the argument and not the file object itself.

Can you try something like this:

```
paramFile = request.FILES['uploadFile'].read()
portfolio = csv.DictReader(paramFile)
```

Comment: this produces an IO error

Error is IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'Magazine.csv'

THanks for your suggestion

Comment: My bad, but basically the idea is to get the path of the uploaded file. Try the one i just edited.

Comment: This gives an attribute error. I too tried this before.
given error is
AttributeError: 'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'temporary_file_path'

Comment: There is a read() method as per the documentation, I tried it, this works.

Comment: i am getting this error : _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not int (did you open the file in text mode?)

Answer (score 21):

This works for **Python 3**

```
import csv
import io

...

csv_file = request.FILES['uploadFile']
decoded_file = csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')
io_string = io.StringIO(decoded_file)
for line in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=';', quotechar='|'):
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 13):

No need to call open on the file, it's already open. You should be able to pass it straight into the DictReader.

Answer (score 10):

**Django 2, Python 3.6**, same problem, half a day of googling, this is the solution that worked for me.

```
form.is_valid:
  csv_file = request.FILES['file']
  csv_file.seek(0)
  reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(csv_file.read().decode('utf-8')))

  for row in reader
     .....
     .....
```

detailed writeup here -> [source](https://andromedayelton.com/2017/04/25/adventures-with-parsing-django-uploaded-csv-files-in-python3/)

Comment: isn't this an answer from *Mark Mishyn* above? :D

Comment: No, Check the link I've posted

Comment: why no? the only difference you are using ```.DictReader()``` instead of ```.reader()```.

Comment: Isn't that a difference? Also, what are you trying to prove?

Answer (score 1):

You get a TypeError, because the built in function open expects a string that is a path to a file.

Does this work?

```
    if form.is_valid():
        request.FILES['uploadFile'].open("rb")
        portfolio = csv.DictReader(request.FILES['uploadFile'].file)
```

Comment: I don't think that file object has an open() method

Comment: It is not working. It says "NoneType: None".. THanks for the suggestion

Comment: Edited the suggestion. The InMemoryUploadedFile class implements the open method from the [django.core.files module](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/)

Comment: Edited request.FILES['uploadFile'].file- This attribute should reference the underlying python file object.