# Python MySQLdb convert list data for CSV output from SELECT

Tags: python, mysql, select

I am struggling with the following (relatively simple) problem. I have am using SELECT query in MySQLdb which returns the following data:

```
select * from extension_recording where filename = "20091030_135711-out.wav";
+----+--------------+------+-------------------------+----------+--------+--------------------+---------------------------+--------+-----------------+------+-------+
| id | extension_id | flow | filename                | filesize | unread | cr_date             | callerid                  | length | callid          | info | party |
+----+--------------+------+-------------------------+----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------------+--------+-----------------+------+-------+
|  1 |           41 | out  | 20091030_135711-out.wav |   264684 | 1      | 2009-10-30 13:57:31 | Some user <01273123456> |     20 | 1256911031.5482 |      | NULL  |
+----+--------------+------+-------------------------+----------+--------+---------------------+---------------------------+--------+-----------------+------+-------+
```

I am trying to use it in the following way:

```
cur.execute ("SELECT * FROM extension_recording WHERE filename = %s;", (file))
csv_result = cur.fetchone()
csv_list.append ([csv_result])
```

This results in a list with Python data types:

```
print csv_list
(1L, 41L, 'out', '20091030_135711-out.wav', 264684L, '1', datetime.datetime(2009, 10, 30, 13, 57, 31), 'Some user <01273123456>', 20L, '1256911031.5482', '', None)
```

I need to output the data to CSV as MySQL data types, therefore I need to convert each field appropriately, i.e. convert the id and extension_id fields to ints rather than longs and convert the date to a string. The point of all this is that I end up with a CSV file something like this:

```
1,41,'out','20091030_135711-out.wav',264684,'1','2009-10-30 13:57:31','Some user <01273123456>',20,'1256911031.5482','',None
```

I can see that I may need to iterate through csv_result but I can't for the life of me see how to do it differently for each data type.

Comment: Are those types consistent? I mean, are the results that you obtain by fetching a row coherent with the types that you have in your table? Which library are you using to connect to your db?

Comment: I'm not really sure I see what the problem is. Just use the `csv` module and it will do pretty much exactly what you want.

Comment: Also the title of your question doesn't really seem related to the problem. Python seems just fine iterating over your select query (though since you're using `cursor.fetchone()` it's doubly irrelevant).

Comment: @Iguananaut sorry I can see how the title seems irrelevant, I thought I could iterate over the _fields_ in csv_result. I'll change it!

Comment: @Iguananaut could you by any chance point me at some docs that show how to use the csv module in that way?

Comment: See @sr2222's answer below. As for the docs, try Google.

Comment: @cynical - yes the data types are consistent, I'm using MySQLdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are those values peculiar? `MySQLdb` does automatic conversion into python types (`int` becomes `long`, `DATE` becomes `datetime`, etc...). Just [csv](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) the tuple returned:

```
import csv  
with open('file.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csv_ = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csv_.writerow(csv_list)
```

This does everything you need.
(If you need quotes, add the `quotechar="'", quoting = csv.CONSTANTHERE` keywords)

File contents:

```
1,41,out,20091030_135711-out.wav,264684,1,2009-10-30 13:57:31,Some user <01273123456>,20,1256911031.5482,,
```

(note: `None` is an empty string using this.)

Comment: This sounds perfect, and makes sense. I'm getting a data type error though `line 176, in <module>
    with open(csvfilename, 'wb') as csvfile:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found`

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: Have made some further progress. Saw this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617286/getting-type-error-while-opening-an-uploaded-csv-file which suggests that the open function requires a path rather than the file variable itself. Changed this and now the CSV file is created, but empty. I can see that the list contains the info to be written to the CSV.

Comment: OK have changed the last line to `csv_.writerows(csv_list)` and it writes the CSV file. But the output line is still `(27L, 43L, 'out', '20091103_134026-out.wav', 28524L, '1', datetime.datetime(2009, 11, 3, 13, 40, 28), 'Some user <01273123456>', 2L, '1257255626.1241', '', None)` where I need it to be `27, 43, 'out', '20091103_134026-out.wav', 28524, 1, 2009-11-03 13:40:28, 'Some user <01273123456>', 2, '1257255626.1241', '', ''`

Comment: That's because you are typing "print tuple_row" in python and assuming it will be the same in the CSV. It wont. (look up `__str__`)

Comment: read @sr2222's comment on the other answer, it sounds exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `csv` module to do the conversion back to string automatically after the fact, or you could initialize your `Connection` object with a custom `conv` value to override the default type conversion dictionary to give you everything as the raw strings returned from MySQL.  Just realize that means you'll have to do all conversion manually, or have a second auto-conversion connection to the same DB, if you want automatic type conversion at any other point in your code.

Comment: I've been reading the csv module docs but I still haven't seen how to change the format that is recorded to the CSV file. I am able to write the file using the following code, but the values still come through incorrectly (ints as 1L, dates as datetime(dd, mm,....  `csvfile = open(tar_path + "/" + client_fileid + ".csv", 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(csvfile, dialect='excel')
for row in csv_list:
  wr.writerow(row)`

Comment: `print csv_list` is going to print the `__str__` for the data therein, meaning you will always get the output you are seeing unless you work with the raw data by changing your `Connection`.  Is the output in the file also incorrectly formatted?

Comment: Yes it is - the output in the file looks identical to `print csv_list`. It seems I need to do some sort of type conversion on the data **before** it goes into the list, but how?

Comment: Wait a minute, why are you wrapping `csv_result` in an outter list before appending it to `csv_list`?  Pretty sure that's going to make your `csv.writer` try to write the whole row as a single element in the row in the file, which will first stringify the contents according to the `__str__()` or `__repr__()` rules for whatever data is contained therein.  Try removing that outter list and just appending the list you get back from MySQLdb, or even more simply, just using `writerows()` on the whole resultset.