# How to open and read file from request.FILES without saving it to disk

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to treat a file in `request.FILES` same as a disk file? I want to do something like this:

```
with open(file_in_request, 'rb') as file:
        #read data from that file
```

Only, I don't want to have to save it to disk first. I will be encrypting that file and save the encrypted file to disk instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**: by modifying `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` Django variable to a large enough value to keep files in memory.

---

By default, Django stores file with a size of 2.5 MB in memory and file larger than that size are stored in a temporary disk location.

The reason for this behavior is that keeping large files in memory can overwhelm your system. [Read it here in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored).

In your case, if you know the max file size and are sure that it won't be large enough to fill up your computer memory you can modify the threshold value `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE` variable to a large enough value to make sure all the files are in memory.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE):

> The maximum size (in bytes) that an upload will be before it gets
>   streamed to the file system. See Managing files for details

Comment: I really don't mind where and how Django stores files of different sizes. I just don't want to save it to disk to be able to read it. What I want to do is read the file, encrypt it, save the encrypted file, and hope that Django will discard the InMemory file later.

Comment: @TahreemIqbal this is your answer then. Modify FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE variable then to something like 10GB

Comment: I added these lines in `settings.py`: `FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 1000 * 1000 * 1000, DATA_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 1000 * 1000 * 1000` and still got exception `TypeError: invalid file: <InMemoryUploadedFile: upoad.csv (application/vnd.ms-excel)>`

Comment: exception occurred on line: `with open(source, 'rb') as file:` where source is a file in `request.FILES`.

Comment: You do not open the uploaded file its already opened you can read it by `paramFile = request.FILES['uploadFile'].read()` see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617286/getting-type-error-while-opening-an-uploaded-csv-file