# Python - CSV sniffer on POST uploaded csv file

Tags: python, django, pandas, csv

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']

    if len(uploaded_file) != 0:
        try:
            df = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)
            id = str(uuid.uuid4())

            read_file = uploaded_file.read(1024)
            if not csv.Sniffer().has_header(read_file):
                df = pd.DataFrame(df.values, columns=[n for n in range(len(df.columns))])

            df.to_csv(f'{TRAIN_FILES}/{id}.csv', index=False)
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'msg': str(e)}, status=500)
        
        return JsonResponse({'msg': id}, status=200)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'msg': 'File is empty'}, status=500)
```

I have this code for uploading a csv, I'm trying to check if the csv has a header using csv.Sniffer, but .has_header complains about it coming in as bytes. What's the proper way to sniff InMemoryUploadedFile?

I also realize that checking if a csv is valid using both sniffer and pandas is less than ideal so if anyone has any suggestions I'm open to it.

Comment: Does [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617286/getting-type-error-while-opening-an-uploaded-csv-file)?

Comment: @Asmus no sadly I did see this post and it doesn't help. They're using a different csv function.

Answer (score 1):

```
            df = pd.read_csv(uploaded_file)
            id = str(uuid.uuid4())

            # Convert to string for sniffer
            stringIO = io.StringIO()
            df.to_csv(stringIO)
            
            if not csv.Sniffer().has_header(stringIO.getvalue()):
                df = pd.DataFrame(df.values, columns=[n for n in range(len(df.columns))])

            df.to_csv(f'{TRAIN_FILES}/{id}.csv', index=False)
```

Here's the solution I came up with, because sniffer has_header requires it to be in string form. I don't know if this is a good way to validate but yea.

Comment: If it works correcly, then it is ok. But, what if file would be large? Then pandas needs to read whole file. Optimal sollution is to read first few lines in binary mode, and convert its binary representation to string (like you have done), then pass it to sniffer only for validation, not for saving.

Comment: well I use Pandas just to ensure the entire csv is formatted correctly. Like maybe the last row is comma delimited incorrectly or something then Pandas should throw an error.