# How to validate CSV file upload on the fly in Django using a custom class-based validator?

Tags: django, csv, django-forms

I have an upload form used to inject CSV file content into the database. So far I'm struggling with validation itself. I switched from function based validator to class based validator so I could pass argument to the validator itself to make it reusable.

**views.py**

```
@login_required
def contact_import(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['file']: 
        form = ContactImportForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            post_result = form.save(commit=True)

            return redirect("/contacts/")
    else:
        form = ContactImportForm()
        
    return render(request,'contact_import_form.html',{
        'form': form
    })
```

**forms.py**

```
class ContactImportForm(forms.Form):
    headers = ["lastname","firstname","email"]
    file = forms.FileField(label='Select your CSV File',validators=[CsvFileValidator(headers)])
    
    def clean_file(self):
        file = self.cleaned_data['file']
        return file
```

**validators.py**

```
class CsvFileValidator(object):
    def __init__(self, headers):
        self.headers = headers
    
    def __call__(self,file):

        # Extension check
        file_extension = os.path.splitext(file.name)[1]
        valid_extensions = [ ".csv", ".CSV"]
        
        if not file_extension.lower() in valid_extensions:
            msg = "Invalid file, select a valid CSV file"
            raise ValidationError("{}".format(msg), status='invalid')

        # File content check
        try:
            csv_format = csv.Sniffer().sniff(file.read(1024))
            file.seek(0,0)    
        except csv.Error:
            msg = "Invalid file, select a valid CSV file"
            raise ValidationError("{}".format(msg), status='invalid')
        
        csv_reader = csv.reader(file.read().splitlines(), dialect=csv_format,delimiter=";")

        for r_index, row in enumerate(csv_reader):

            # CSV headers check
            if r_index == 0:
                if sorted(self.headers) != sorted(row):
                    msg = "Missing or invalid headers"
                    raise ValidationError("{}".format(msg), status='invalid')   
     
            # Skip blank line
            if not "".join(str(field) for field in row):
                continue
        
        return True
```

**contact_import_form.html**
HTML template, relevant parts only:

```
<div class="messages">
{% if form.errors %}
    {% if form.non_field_errors %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        <p class="text-danger"><strong>AN error occured during form validation</strong>
        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
            {{error}}
        {% endfor %}  
        </p>
   
    {% endif %}
    
    {% for field in form %}
        {% if field.errors %}
            <p class="text-danger"><strong>{{ field.name }} :</strong> {{ field.errors }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
     </div>
{% endif %}
</div>

<form id="contact-import-form" method="post" action=" " role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form.file.label_tag }}
        {{ form.file }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">Valider</button>
        <a href="${%url 'contact_list' %}" id="cancel" name="cancel" class="btn btn-default">Annuler</a>
      </div>
    </div>    
</form>
```

For now I have an error after submitting the form:

> TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

This error points to file content check in my validator, specifically line above:

```
csv_format = csv.Sniffer().sniff(file.read(1024))
```

How to implement this custom class-based validator to work properly? Also I imagine that missing code to update the database should live in the view in `if form.is_valid():` code block.

How to validate CSV file upload on the fly with my class-based validator and subsenquently use its data to populate a model?

Comment: When passed to CsvFileValidator, 'file' type is "'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile".  Wrapping file within a io.TextIOWrapper seems ok. But still, exception raised from Validators don't appear in my template.

Comment: form validation works as expected but no exception message appears in form.errors or form.non_field_errors. How to make validation exception messages available in those?

Comment: It seems that the validator itself is to blame, but I don't know how to troubleshoot the issue properly. Without validator, file can be read if form is valid.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the type of the file, `file.read(1024)` does not return a string, to fix this you should decode the output as `csv_format = csv.Sniffer().sniff(file.read(1024).decode('UTF-8'))`.

Answer (score 0):

When a Form's clean method is called and you want to check the file contents, you need to know how to properly open the `InMemoryUploadedFile` type. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41911251) answer shows how to open an uploaded file.

As donmelchior pointed out above in a comment, it looks like your `CsvFileValidator` class is opening the file incorrectly. Try something like

```
import csv
import io

decoded_file = file.read().decode("utf-8")
io_string = io.StringIO(decoded_file)
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(io_string)
```